# Use of FROM keyword on DELETE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete

The BOL and many other sources point out:

> FROM
>   Is an optional keyword that can be used between the DELETE keyword and the target
>   table_or_view_name, or rowset_function_limited.

I'm used to write `DELETE` sentences without the `FROM`. I've made some searches but can't find where the `FROM` is mandatory. Can anyone point out a situation where it should be mandatory? Or is always optional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one case where it would be hard to write it without:

```
DELETE /* FROM */ t1    -- this FROM is optional
  FROM dbo.t1           -- this FROM is mandatory
  INNER JOIN dbo.t2 AS t2
  ON t1.key = t2.key
  WHERE t2.key IN (1,2,3);
```

Or:

```
DELETE /* FROM */ t1    -- this FROM is optional
  FROM dbo.t1           -- this FROM is mandatory
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.t2
    WHERE key IN (1,2,3)
    AND key = t1.key
  );
```

The `FROM` in the initial spot (e.g. `DELETE **FROM** t1 FROM dbo.t1 ...`) is optional, just as Books Online says. Why do you think it ever should be mandatory? Borrowing from Thomas' answer, which he gracefully deleted, the following are identical:

```
DELETE Sales.SalesOrderDetail WHERE SalesOrderID = -1;

DELETE FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail WHERE SalesOrderID = -1;
```

This is similar to `INSERT` - the following are absolutely 100% equivalent, and you don't ever have to write `INTO`:

```
INSERT dbo.t1(key) VALUES(1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO dbo.t1(key) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I don't think it should be mandatory, just was asking for a situation where without it the sentence will not work. By your samples I get to the conclusion that if `mytable AS x` is used then `FROM` will be mandatory. Correct?

Comment: @Yaroslav no, the `AS` has nothing to do with it - it's the fact that you are deleting from a join or more complex expression than just a single table. I've updated the example to show this.

Comment: Ouch! Now I got it.